# Asymptotics of $\frac{\sum _{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {2(n-2i) \choose n-2i} {n \choose 2i} {4i \choose 2i}}{2^{3n - 1}}$, is it $\frac{2}{\pi n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

I am trying to work out the asymptotics of 
$$\frac{\sum _{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {2(n-2i) \choose n-2i} {n \choose 2i} {4i \choose 2i}}{2^{3n - 1}}.$$

My numerical experiments suggest it might be $\frac{2}{\pi n}$.

The only thing I know to do is to apply Stirling's formula. So we get ${4i \choose 2i} \sim 2^{4i+1/2}/\sqrt{2i\pi}$ I think. Similarly we get ${2(n-2i) \choose n-2i} \sim 2^{(n-2i)+1/2}/\sqrt{(n-2i)\pi}$ I think.  Even assuming these are right, I not sure what to do with ${n \choose 2i}$.

Comment: Summands $a_i$ attain their maximum at $i=n/4$. So the numerator can be estimated from above as $a_{n/4}\times \frac{n}{2}$. The lower bound is obviously $a_{n/4}$

Comment: Numerical evaluations confirm your initial suspicions.

Comment: @Lucian Thank you very much for checking!

Comment: @felipa: Have you tried writing $\displaystyle{n\choose2i}\le{n\choose[n/2]}$ ?

Comment: After applying Lucian's recommendation, Vandermonde's identity will simplify the summation, and what's left should go through easily after applying Stirling's Formula (I think).

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish I can't quite see how to apply Vandermonde's identity etc. in a way that gives the desired asymptotics. If you can see it, would you be able to add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that evaluates part  of the sum and locates the OEIS
entry for the remaining one,  thereby it is hoped facilitating further
investigation.

Suppose we are interested in the asymptotics of
$$\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
{n\choose 2q} {4q\choose 2q} {2n-4q\choose n-2q}.$$

Introduce
$${4q\choose 2q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{4q}}{z^{2q+1}} \; dz$$

and
$${2n-4q\choose n-2q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n-4q}}{w^{n-2q+1}} \; dw.$$

This gives for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
{n\choose 2q}  \frac{(1+z)^{4q}}{z^{2q}}
\frac{w^{2q}}{(1+w)^{4q}}
\; dw \; dz$$

This has two pieces, namely
$$A_1 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n+1}}
\left(1+\frac{(1+z)^{2}}{z}\frac{w}{(1+w)^2}\right)^n
\; dw \; dz$$
and
$$A_2 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n+1}}
\left(1-\frac{(1+z)^{2}}{z}\frac{w}{(1+w)^2}\right)^n
\; dw \; dz.$$

Start with $A_2$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{(z(1+w)^2-w(1+z)^2)^n}{z^n(1+w)^{2n}}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
(z(1+w)^2-w(1+z)^2)^n
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
(wz-1)^n (w-z)^n
\; dw \; dz.$$

Extracting the inner residue we get
$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} z^q (-1)^{n-q}
{n\choose n-q} (-1)^q z^q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}^2 z^{2q} (-1)^{n-2q}.$$

Extracting the outer residue from this we get zero when $n$ is odd and
$${n\choose n/2}^2$$ when $n$ is even, giving the sequence
(up to the $1/2$ multiplier)
$$0, 4, 0, 36, 0, 400, 0, 4900, 0, 63504, 0, 853776, 0, 
11778624,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A002894](https://oeis.org/A002894).

This can be treated with Stirling to get
$$\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\pi n}.$$

We see that  on dividing by $2^{3n-1}$ and including  the $1/2$ factor
we get
$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}\pi n}$$
which is an asymptotically lower order term.

Unfortunately there seems not to be a closed form expression for $A_1$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
(z(1+w)^2+w(1+z)^2)^n
\; dw \; dz$$
because the central term does not factor. We get the sequence
(factor $1/2$ not included)
$$4, 20, 112, 676, 4304, 28496, 194240, 1353508, 9593104, 
68906320,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A081085](https://oeis.org/A081085).

Among  the references  listed therein  we find  that this  sequence is
asymptotic to
$$\frac{2^{3n+1}}{\pi n}$$
which on including the $1/2$ multiplier from $A_1$ and dividing
by $2^{3n-1}$ does indeed yield
$$\frac{2}{\pi n}$$ as conjectured.